# Add validation errors to existing form with javascript?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, validation

I have a ASP.NET MVC 4 where I use client and server side validations with validation attributes.

The form will be properly validated before sending it with ajax like this :

```
function ValidateFormAndAjaxSubmit(formId, callingElement) {

    if (IsNotDblClick(callingElement.id)) {
        var _form = $("#" + formId);

        var validator = _form.validate();
        var anyError = false;

        _form.find("input").each(function () {
            if (!validator.element(this)) { // validate every input element inside this step
                anyError = true;
            }
        });

        if (anyError) {
            window.latestClick = '';
            return false; // exit if any error found    
        }

        $.post(_form.attr("action"), _form.serialize(), function (data) {

            if (data.Success) {

            }
            else {

            }

            alert("Win");
            window.latestClick = '';
            //check the result and do whatever you want
        })
    }
}
```

The form looks like this :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("JEdit", "Post", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmEditPost" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    ...
}
```

There will be made extra validations on the serverside and this is stored in a returning class like this :

```
public class JEditResult
    {
        public Boolean Success = false;
        public string TitleErrMessage;
        public string TextErrMessage;
        public string LinkErrMessage;
        public string TagErrMessage;
        public string OtherErrMessage;
    }
```

Now I need to put these validations into the form as if thay was validated on the client. How do I do this?

Comment: Are you using model binding and have you added validation attributes to your model? You probably don't want to have your own result class like you've created with the JEditResult. Looks like you are duplicating functionality that is built in to MVC. Can you post the code for your model and your action method?

Comment: Get rid of all that input looping business and just use [valid()](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid). Also FYI - it is "server" not "service" - like the web _server_. Get it?

Comment: @jesus.tesh thanks, that worked fine but the main problem on how to handle returning validations is not yet solved.

Answer (score 2):

I use the following extension method:

```
public static JsonResult JsonValidation(this ModelStateDictionary state, JsonRequestBehavior behavior = JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet) {
    var result = new JsonResult {
        Data = new {
            success = false,
            Tag = "ValidationError",
            State = from e in state
                    where e.Value.Errors.Count > 0
                    select new {
                        Name = e.Key,
                        Errors = (e.Value.Errors.Select(x => x.ErrorMessage)
                            .Concat(e.Value.Errors.Where(x => x.Exception != null).Select(x => x.Exception.Message)))
                            .Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).Select(x => x)
                    }
        }
    };
    result.JsonRequestBehavior = behavior;
    return result;
}
```

Then use it within my code like so:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid == false) {
    Response.StatusCode = 400;
    return ModelState.JsonValidation();
}
```

I also have some standard js code I use:

```
// JSON validation
function validateResponse(form, response) {
    var data = getResponseValidationObject(response);
    if (!data) return true;

    var validator = form.validate();
    var container = form.find("[data-valmsg-summary=true]");
    var list = container.find("ul");
    if (!list) return;

    container.addClass("validation-summary-errors").removeClass("validation-summary-valid");
    list.empty().show();
    $.each(data.State, function (i, item) {
        list.append("<li>" + item.Errors.join("</li><li>") + "</li>");
    });
    return false;
}

// JSON validation
function getResponseValidationObject(response) {
    if (response && response.Tag && response.Tag == "ValidationError")
        return response;
    return null;
}
```

Then within my ajax post I check the return response for validity:

```
var json = $.parseJSON(response.responseText);
var isValid = validateResponse($("#form"), json);
// Do something here...
```

The `validateResponse` function will automatically add errors to the forms validation summary (assuming there is one).

Comment: This looks like the solution Im looking for! Nice work. I will try it out

Comment: Thanks. :) It works pretty well, I am sure it'll do the trick for you too.

Comment: I found a problem with my code, the inner post function will not be triggered becouse we set StatusCode to 400(I think) how should I handle this? Could I ignore the StatusCode? Or is there a error function for the jquery.post?

Comment: Yes, there is .error() for $.post - it is basically just $.ajax with "POST" pre-set. It behaves the same way though. However, since you know the validity in the intitial post return, you could probably skip the status code and it could still work for you.